# How to filter the data use equal or greater than condition in the url?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I can use the bellow link to filter the `id=16`'s data:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/physicalservertask/list_for_home_workpanel/?id=16
```

this is my list api view:

```
class PhysicalServerTaskListAPIView(ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = PhysicalServerTaskListSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    def get_queryset(self):
        query_params = self.request.query_params
        filters = {'{}__contains'.format(key): value
                   for key, value in query_params.items()
                   }

        return PhysicalServerTask.objects.filter(**filters)
```

I have a question, how can I query the `id>= 16`'s data list through the url?

I mean whether I can through the:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/physicalservertask/list_for_home_workpanel/?id__gte=16
```

to filter the data.

I know I can in the ListAPIView query like this:

```
id_gte = self.request.query_params.copy().get('id_gte')
...
qs = PhysicalServerTask.objects.filter(**filters)
qs.filter(Q(id__gte=id__gte))
```

but whether there is a more convenient way to realize this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can add a `filter_fields` attribute to your view like this:

```
class PhysicalServerTaskListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    ...
    filter_fields = {
        'id': ['gte', 'lte']
    }
```

That will allow you to make queries such as:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/physicalservertask/list_for_home_workpanel/?id__gte=16

http://localhost:8000/api/physicalservertask/list_for_home_workpanel/?id__lte=16
```

For that to work, you will need to [install django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/install.html), and add the `DjangoFilterBackend` to your `settings.py` if it is not already there:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',)
}
```

`filter_fields` is commonly used with a list of model fields for exact lookups. However, a dictionary can also be supplied, like in the example above, which maps model fields to other types of lookups - such as `gte` and `lte`.

More information on the `filter_fields` attribute can be found [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/rest_framework.html#using-the-filter-fields-shortcut). More information on the list/dict format of `filter_fields` is [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filterset.html#fields).

Comment: thanks for pointing out that possibility of providing a dict as filter_fields. Works like a charm!

Comment: To make consistency with other parts of the  `django-filter` library, I would rename `filter_fields` to `filterset_fields`